# WebView calling Java code in Android (inner workings of Javascript bridges)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-webview, npapi

I am trying to figure out how WebView is able to give javascript code access to Java code via addJavascriptInterface, as well as redirect prompt and alert javascript functions to the event handlers (onJsPrompt, onJsAlert). What I've understood so far is that there is a mechanism called JNI, we can make certain Java functionality invokable by the code outside JVM through the use of JNI. There is also something called NPAPI that allows the use of plugins in web applications. A combination of these two will be used to allow javascript code running in a WebView to invoke methods of the exported Java class (via addJavascriptInterface).

However, I am not able to see how prompt and alert functions are redirected. Is it something similar to what I've described above, and if so how?

Also, it looks like NPAPI is deprecated in Chromium. Does this mean that it isn't used in WebViews anymore either and if so, what does it use now?

Thanks very much in advance for all the help!

Comment: NPAPI is not relevant for browsers on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

It used to work like you described. The web browser loaded NPAPI a plugin with native code. The plugin then calls to Java through JNI.

You can learn more about it here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=addJavascriptInterface&sq=package:chromium&type=cs
then go deeper to addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface(),

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/ContentViewCore.java&q=addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

Comment: Thank you! Are these the implementations for the webview itself or the chrome browser on Android?